# How can one select an application to switch to in task switcher with track pad (MacBook Pro, Mac OS X Snow Leopard)?

Tags: macos, switch, tasks

Four finger swipe left/right -> Task switcher shows up (a horizontal bar with app symbols).

Two finger swipe -> highlights an icon and shows app name.

?? -> switches to highlighted app.
Since the highlighting is independent of the mouse cursor, a click doesn't work here without moving the mouse cursor. But I don't want this (locate mouse cursor, move the extra mile..).

Maybe Better Touch Tool allows to configure a click to act as SPACE or RETURN in the task switcher? But how did Apple intend to use this?

Comment: I think you meant **four** finger swipe left/right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's four finger tap.

I don't think Better TouchTool have any option for changing this, tho.

Comment: Ahh! No need for Better TouchTool then. Thanks.